# '07 MacBook Pro -- OS X will not accept disk 2 during a fresh reinstallation

Tags: macbook-pro, install

My 2007 MacBook Pro is in need of a fresh OS X reinstall.  Initially, I wanted to Erase and install everything eg,. Snow Leopard, Leopard, and the original OS X, however I am now sorry for trying because Disk 2 of my original copies will not load, but rather is continually ejected. When I attempt to boot, 'Installer' will ask that I insert 'Disk 2' to continue the installation, however will merely try without success before repeating this process over.

On my iPad, after searching the Internet for solutions to my dilemma, the only way I found to boot my MacBook is to press the 'alt/option' key with the 'power button' simultaneously until I arrive to my desktop, and at that point all appears normal, however, this is such a bother.  Aside from buying a new MacBook, are there any suggestions I might consider?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

[Mac OS X 10.4: Repeatedly asked to insert Install DVD Disc 2 during installation](http://support.apple.com/kb/ta24615)

But why start on such an early OS?

Comment: I'm sorry MK, your inititial fix may have worked, but my partially paralyzed hands are far too slow to press and hold multiple keys during the brief booting process.  In any case, depressing the 'alt' key as I had earlier is no longer an option; after I 'power on'my MacBook simply displays the blinking dark grey folder with a question mark.  Would you happen to have any other recommendations?  Thank you!